# максимальная длина правильной скобочной подстроки

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки, стек

Дано: строка состоящая только из скобок, например: `())(()))`.
Нужно вычислить длину самой большой правильной скобочной подстроки.
В приведенном примере это будет 4, в `(()(())` - 6, в `()()` - тоже 4. Строка может быть очень длинной (100000 символов), программа должна выполнятся меньше чем за 35 мс.

[Оригинал задания](https://www.codewars.com/kata/584c3e45710dca21be000088).

Первый мой вариант был таким:

```
count = 0
word = []

for i in s:
    if i == '(':
        word.append(i)
    if i == ')' and word and word[-1] == '(':
        word.pop()
        count += 2
    
ic(count)
```

Но этот скрипт считал просто общее количество правильных пар, т.е. в строке `())(()))` получалось 6, вместо положенных 4...

Следующая попытка:

```
stack = []
count = 0
word = []
for i in s:
    if i == '(':
        word += [i]
    if i == ')' and word and word[-1] == '(':
        word.pop()
        count += 2
    if i == ')' and not word:
        stack += [count]
        count = 0

    stack += [count]


ic(max(stack) if stack else 0)
```

Теперь скрипт замечательно считает `())(()))` и получает требуемые 4, `(()(())` - получает 6, но валится на `()()`.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Как усовершенствовать скрипт, а может стоит попробовать совсем другой подход?

Comment: Вы бы описАли реализованный алгоритм-то...

Comment: реализованный алгоритм под названием следующая попытка

Comment: Приведите **точную** формулировку задачи.

Comment: Хм, ну если вас не устраивает русским языком разжеванное задание, то вот вам "точная формулировка задачи": https://www.codewars.com/kata/584c3e45710dca21be000088

Comment: Конечно, не устраивает, когда это искажает смысл задачи или позволяет интерпретировать её разными способами. Ссылку или формулировку с ограничениями (размер строк) лучше внести в вопрос.

Comment: Поправил заголовок, текст и метки. Надеюсь стало ближе к оригиналу.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = '((()))())))(((()((()())()((())()'

count = [0]*(len(s) + 1)
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if s[i] == '(':
        continue
    start = i - 1 - count[i - 1]
    if start < 0:
        continue
    if s[start] != '(':
        continue
    count[i] = i - start + 1 + count[start - 1]

print(max(count))
```

---

8

Если текущий символ s[i] на текущей правильной последовательности(i=0 ... 2n-1) равен '(',
то мы  переходим к следующему символу.
Если же текущий символ равен ')', то мы должны прибавить к ответу d[2n-i-1][depth+1],
тем самым учитывая, что в этой позиции мог бы стоять символ '('
(который бы привёл к лексикографически меньшей последовательности, чем текущая);
величину  depth (баланс) мы не трогаем т.к. у нас правильная последовательность depth=0.
Если i=0, то ответ : d[0][0] = 1,все остальные d[0][j] = 0 пропускаем, if s[start] будет '(' ,
то получается цепочка не закрыта, тоже пропускаем.

https://e-maxx.ru/algo/bracket_sequences#7

Comment: Да, можно посмотреть какой тест не проходит:
Input: '((()))())))(((()((()())()((())()': 16 should equal 8, например и еще кучу других

Comment: Чуточку углубился в теорию, можешь еще потестить? Я поправил, покажи какой тест не проходит. Теорию брал тут: `https://e-maxx.ru/algo/bracket_sequences#7`